Row-Level Security in Visual Studio 2022 Tabular Modeling Not Working
I'm adding row-level security to a tabular model using Visual Studio. The data will be processed and stored in Azure and analyzed in Excel. Somehow, I'm not sure how yet, the Azure component means USERNAME() needs to equal email address instead of NTID.
I've based this model's tables, relationships and role off of other tabular models with functioning row-level security. When I connect to my model in Excel, however, I see all records and not the records I should be restricted to when I log in with my Windows Authentication.
This is a similar question to others here and elsewhere online, however I haven't found a solution that resolves my ineffective RLS logic.
-- Fact table.
CREATE TABLE dbo.facts (
  [RecordID] INT,
  [AccessGroupID] INT,
  [facts] VARCHAR(200)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.facts
VALUES (1, 1, 'lorem ipsum'),
       (2, 1, 'dolor sit amet'),
       (3, 2, 'lorem ipsum');

-- Bridge table prevents many-to-many relationship.
SELECT DISTINCT [AccessGroupID]
INTO dbo.bridge
FROM dbo.facts;

-- Security table maps user to facts. 
CREATE TABLE dbo.security(
  [UserID] CHAR(1),
  [Email] VARCHAR(50),
  [AccessGroupID] INT,
);

INSERT INTO dbo.security
VALUES ('a', 'a@z.com', 1),
       ('a', 'a@z.com', 2),
       ('b', 'b@z.com', 1),
       ('c', 'c@z.com', 2);

The relationships are dbo.bridge -> dbo.facts one-to-many, dbo.bridge -> dbo.security one-to-many.
In Visual Studio Tabular Model Explorer > Roles > Role Filters I've set up the following DAX logic:
dbo.security = FALSE();

dbo.bridge = 
  dbo.bridge[AccessGroupID] =
    LOOKUPVALUE(
      dbo.security[AccessGroupID],
      dbo.security[EMAIL], USERNAME(),
      dbo.security[AccessGroupID], dbo.bridge[AccessGroupID]
    )

UserID 'a' should see all three facts in the fact table; user 'b' should see RecordIDs 1 and 2, and user 'c' should see record 3.
However, my model shows everybody all three records. What am I missing and why?

I have also tried changing the filter direction in the many-to-one relationship between dbo.security -> dbo.bridge from "To dbo.security" to "To Both Tables", removing the DAX filter on dbo.bridge and changing the DAX filter on dbo.security to '=dbo.security[Email] = USERNAME'. This didn't work.
